# Looking to optimize the rendering of lines in webgl (using the three.js library)

Tags: performance, three.js, webgl

Recently started learning webGL and decided to use the Three.js library.

Currently, in addition to, rendering over 100K of cubes, I'm also trying to render lines between those cubes (over 100K).

The problem with rendering occurs when I try to draw lines, NOT cubes.  Rendering 100k cubes was relatively fast. Even rendering those 100K+ lines is relatively fast but when I try to zoom/pan using the TrackballControls, the FPS goes down to almost 0.

I've searched StackOverflow and various other sites in order to improve the performance of my application.   I've used the merging geometries technique, the delayed rendering of lines ( basically x number of cubes/lines at a time using a timeout in js), and adjusting the appearance of the lines to require the most minimal rendering time.

Are there any other methods in constructing the lines so that the rendering/fps aren't affected?  I'm building a group of lines and THEN adding it to the scene. But is there a way that merging is possible with lines?  Should I be constructing my lines using different objects?

I just find it strange that I can easily render/pan/zoom/maintain a high fps with over 100k cubes but with lines (which is the most basic form of geometry besides a point), everything crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You have found out (the hard way) where do graphics chip vendors put their focus on their devise drivers. But that is to be expected in 3D graphics as lines (yes the most basic geometry) are not used my many games so they do not receive much attention as polygons do. You can take a look at the example webgl_buffergeometry_lines.html which is probably the faster way to draw lines.